# Add forward slash to string

Tags: c++, string

I want to make a string "test/" but I can't add the slash after the initial string. Any idea why and how?

```
string imgpath="test";
strcat(imgpath,"/");
```

This is what I've tried so far.
I get

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'strcat' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *'
```

And another

```
imgpath="test"+"/";

Error   1   error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers
```

Comment: `strcat` isn't meant to be used for `std::string`. Use the second code-snippet [or use C style strings, but that's a much poorer choice]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`std::string::operator+=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) instead of `strcat()`.

```
string imgpath="test";
imgpath += "/";
```

As for your second example

```
imgpath=std::string("test") +"/";
```

Comment: Check second example.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: your second example isn't equivalent to what was posted here

Comment: I know but that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: May I ask how you only have one reputation with that many questions, answers, and badges @πάντα ῥεῖ?

Comment: @Dan The user is currently suspended on SO, thus its reputation is set to 1. For more information, please read [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

Comment: @AndrewT. Ah okay. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat) is used to append to a c-string. You should just use [`string::append`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) or [`string::operator+=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D):

```
imgpath.append("/");
imgpath += "/";
```

For your second question: `"asd"` is a `char *`, not a `std::string`. So it doesn't have a useful `+` operator. This code should look like:

```
string x = string("asd") + "xyz";
```

Comment: why don't you have to convert "xyz" to string, too?

Comment: In this case, we're doing `std::string + char *`, which is usefully defined. `char * + char *` is not a thing.